# Follow on - Multiple Sums in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Thanks to Quassnoi before who gave me the answer I was looking for - this led to a seperate problem though. Current code:

```
SELECT     i.CONCOM, COALESCE (SUM(t.LOGMINS), 0) AS TotalWithoutNew
FROM         INQUIRY AS i INNER JOIN
                  TIMELOG AS t ON t.INQUIRY_ID = i.INQUIRY_ID INNER JOIN
                  PROD AS P ON i.PROD_ID = P.PROD_ID INNER JOIN
                  CATEGORY AS C ON P.CATEGORY_ID = C.CATEGORY_ID
WHERE     (DATEPART(month, i.ESCDATE) = DATEPART(month, GETDATE()) - 1) AND (DATEPART(year,   i.ESCDATE) = DATEPART(year, DATEADD(m, - 1, GETDATE()))) AND 
                  (C.CATEGORY_ID <> '30')
GROUP BY i.CONCOM
ORDER BY TotalWithoutNew DESC
```

This brings back exactly what I want (C.CATEGORY_ID <> 30) is not included in the initial column marked as TotalWithoutNew. I also need the value WITH it in as well though. Is there any way to have another column called TotalWithNew that includes all CATEGORY_IDs? I am certain learning a lot of new query language today!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT     i.CONCOM, 
COALESCE (SUM(CASE WHEN C.CATEGORY_ID = '30' THEN 0 ELSE t.LOGMINS END), 0) AS TotalAllID,
COALESCE (SUM(t.LOGMINS), 0) AS TotalWithoutNew
FROM         INQUIRY AS i INNER JOIN
                  TIMELOG AS t ON t.INQUIRY_ID = i.INQUIRY_ID INNER JOIN
                  PROD AS P ON i.PROD_ID = P.PROD_ID INNER JOIN
                  CATEGORY AS C ON P.CATEGORY_ID = C.CATEGORY_ID
WHERE     (DATEPART(month, i.ESCDATE) = DATEPART(month, GETDATE()) - 1) AND (DATEPART(year,   i.ESCDATE) = DATEPART(year, DATEADD(m, - 1, GETDATE()))) 
GROUP BY i.CONCOM
ORDER BY TotalWithoutNew DESC
```

Note: I haven't tried but I hope you get the idea of using [`CASE WHEN ...`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).

Comment: The trick being the use of CASE WHEN THEN to turn values to 0, if they're in CategoryID 30.  (I think it's generally nicer to explain things rather than hide it in the code.)

Comment: That worked great, and thanks for the explanation Dems I was wondering! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT i.CONCOM
    , COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN C.CATEGORY_ID <> 30 THEN t.LOGMINS END), 0)
         AS TotalWithoutNew
    , COALESCE(SUM(t.LOGMINS), 0) AS TotalWithNew
FROM INQUIRY AS i INNER JOIN
    TIMELOG AS t ON t.INQUIRY_ID = i.INQUIRY_ID INNER JOIN
    PROD AS P ON i.PROD_ID = P.PROD_ID INNER JOIN
    CATEGORY AS C ON P.CATEGORY_ID = C.CATEGORY_ID
WHERE (DATEPART(month, i.ESCDATE) = DATEPART(month, GETDATE()) - 1)
AND (DATEPART(year,   i.ESCDATE) = DATEPART(year, DATEADD(m, - 1, GETDATE())))
GROUP BY i.CONCOM
ORDER BY TotalWithoutNew DESC
```